# NoSuchMethodException org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.<init>()?

Tags: java, spring-security, configuration

I am modifying spring-security from spring security-3 to spring security-4.x. And I followed this Link:-[enter link description here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html)

My configuration is :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

    <!-- This is where we configure Spring-Security --> 
    <security:http  entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"> 
    <security:custom-filter position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" ref="concurrencyFilter" /> 
    <security:custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="myAuthFilter" /> 

    <security:session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas"/> 
    <security:custom-filter ref="filter" before="FILTER_SECURITY_INTERCEPTOR" /> 
    <security:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/login"/> 

    </security:http> 

    <bean id="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"  class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"> 
    <property name="loginFormUrl" value="/login"/> 
    </bean> 

    <bean id="concurrencyFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter"> 
    <property name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" /> 
    <property name="expiredUrl" value="/login" /> 
    </bean> 

    <bean id="myAuthFilter" class= "org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter"> 
    <property name="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" ref="sas" /> 
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" /> 
    <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="failureHandler"/> 
    <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successHandler"/>
    </bean> 

    <bean id="sas" class= "org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy"> 
    <constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" /> 
    <property name="maximumSessions" value="1" /> 
    <property name="exceptionIfMaximumExceeded" value="true"/>
    </bean> 

    <bean id="successHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler"> 
    <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/home"/> 
    </bean> 

    <bean id="failureHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler"> 
    <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/login?failed=true"/> 
    </bean> 

    <bean id="sessionRegistry" class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" /> 

    <bean id="filter" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor"> 
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/> 
        <property name="accessDecisionManager"> 
    <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased"> 
        <property name="decisionVoters" > 
    <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter"> 
        <property name="rolePrefix" value="ROLE_"/> 
    </bean> 
        </property> 
    </bean> 
        </property> 
        <property name="securityMetadataSource" ref="dbFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource"/> 
    </bean> 

    <!-- Authentication Manger config --> 
    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"> 
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="authenticationService"/> 
    </security:authentication-manager> 
    </beans>
```

And I am getting Exception like this:-

```
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy] for bean with name 'sas' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springs-security.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy from [Module "deployment.CreditProcessClient.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy] for bean with name 'sas' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springs-security.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy from [Module "deployment.CreditProcessClient.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
11:15:41,175 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-6) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'concurrencyFilter' while setting constructor argument with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'concurrencyFilter' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springs-security.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.<init>()
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy] for bean with name 'sas' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springs-security.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy from [Module org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy] for bean with name 'sas' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springs-security.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy from [Module java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'concurrencyFilter' while setting constructor argument with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'concurrencyFilter' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springs-security.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:382) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:634) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'concurrencyFilter' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springs-security.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1105) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1050) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 40 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:85) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1098) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:80) [spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 49 more

11:15:41,182 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-oss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'concurrencyFilter' while setting constructor argument with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'concurrencyFilter' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springs-security.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.<init>()
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy] for bean with name 'sas' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springs-security.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy from [Module "deployment.CreditProcessClient.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy] for bean with name 'sas' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springs-security.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy from [Module io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:223)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:87)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.start(UndertowDeploymentService.java:72)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'concurrencyFilter' while setting constructor argument with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'concurrencyFilter' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springs-security.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.<init>()
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy] for bean with name 'sas' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springs-security.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy from [Module org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy] for bean with name 'sas' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springs-security.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy from [Module  io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:194)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'concurrencyFilter' while setting constructor argument with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'concurrencyFilter' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springs-security.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.<init>()
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'concurrencyFilter' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springs-security.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.<init>()

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1098)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178) [rt.jar:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:80)
    ... 49 more
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'concurrencyFilter' while setting constructor argument with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'concurrencyFilter' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springs-security.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.<init>()
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy] for bean with name 'sas' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springs-security.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy from [Module \"deployment.CreditProcessClient.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy] for bean with name 'sas' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springs-security.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy from [Module \"deployment.CreditProcessClient.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'concurrencyFilter' while setting constructor argument with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'concurrencyFilter' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springs-security.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.<init>()
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy] for bean with name 'sas' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springs-security.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy from [Module \"deployment.CreditProcessClient.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy] for bean with name 'sas' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springs-security.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy from [Module \"deployment.CreditProcessClient.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'concurrencyFilter' while setting constructor argument with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'concurrencyFilter' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springs-security.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.<init>()
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'concurrencyFilter' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springs-security.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.<init>()
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.<init>()
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.<init>()"}}
```

Please help me to modify some changes in this config file.

Answer (score 5):

```
<bean id="concurrencyFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter"> 
  <property name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" /> 
  <property name="expiredUrl" value="/login" /> 
</bean>
```

`ConcurrentSessionFilter` uses constructor-argument dependency injection.  Change to

```
<bean id="concurrencyFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter"> 
  <constructor-arg ref="sessionRegistry" /> 
  <constructor-arg value="/login" /> 
</bean>
```

Comment: thanks for speed reply.. still getting same exception

Comment: I don't think it _exactly_ the same exception. Check carefully.

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy] for bean with name 'sas' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springs-security.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy from [Module "deployment.CreditProcessClient.war:main" from Service Module Loader] This kind of exception i am getting

Comment: Do i need to modify entair <property> tag to <constructor> tag

Comment: The exception in your comment is completely different from the one in your original post. You need to read the Javadoc for each bean you are instantiating to determine if it uses setter injection or constructor-arg injection and modify your configuration appropriately.  If you want to ask about the new exception, post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I was migrating from spring security 3.1.4 to spring security 5.2.0 and I had the same error.

I was using this this:

```
<beans:bean id="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
    <beans:property name="exceptionIfMaximumExceeded" value="true"/>
    <beans:property name="maximumSessions" value="4"/>
</beans:bean>
```

But changed it to:

```
<beans:bean id="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
    <beans:property name="exceptionIfMaximumExceeded" value="true"/>
    <beans:property name="maximumSessions" value="4"/>
</beans:bean>
```

And then it worked for me.